# Comparing the slackness of Jensen's inequality for some coupled random variables

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be convex and $X,Y$ be random variables with a coupling such that $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X=x] = x$. A straightforward application of Jensen's inequality gives that $\mathbb{E}[f(Y) - f(X)] > 0$.

We define the conditional expectation $\mu(y) := \mathbb{E}[X\mid Y=y]$. Jensen's similarly gives that $\mathbb{E}[f(X) - f(\mu(Y))] > 0$.

My question is, what conditions on $f$ suffice to guarantee that,
$$\mathbb{E}[f(X) - f(\mu(Y))] \leq  \mathbb{E}[f(Y) - f(X)]? \tag{1}\label{1}$$
My hunch is that when $f$ is convex and the second derivative $f''$ is convex, $\eqref{1}$.

**Intuition**

Here's why I believe the condition $f''$ is convex, or something similar, should suffice: The value of $\mathbb{E}[f(Y) - f(X)]$ can be expressed as some sort of integral of $f''$ on the range between $X$ and $Y$ (corresponding to the slack in Jensen's inequality). Similarly, $\mathbb{E}[f(X) - f(\mu(Y))]$ can be expressed as a corresponding integral of $f''$ on the range between $\mu(Y)$ and $X$. The difference is that $\mu(Y)$ is "less spread out" than $X$ which in turn is "less spread out" than $Y$, where "less spread out" can be formalized in a stochastic domination sense like the convex order defined [here](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-34675-5).

Therefore, the range of values for which $f''$ impacts $\mathbb{E}[f(Y) - f(X)]$ should be a more "spread out" range than when it impacts $\mathbb{E}[f(X) - f(\mu(Y))]$. Seems like something akin to convexity of $f''$ captures what we want here.

However, formalizing the above intuition quickly devolves into messy expressions. If the conjecture is true, I imagine there is a simple reason.

**What I know**

I know $\eqref{1}$ holds for $f(x) = x^2$, but not for all convex $f$ (it fails for $f(x) = |x|)$.

For the case of $f(x) = x^2$: Fix any choice of $y$. Then,
$$\mathbb{E}_{X}[(X-y)^2\mid Y=y]  \geq \mathrm{Var}[X \mid Y=y] = \mathbb{E}[X^2 \mid Y=y]-\mu(y)^2 .$$

Taking the expectation of both above sides over the choice of $Y$ gives that

$$\mathbb{E}_{X,Y}[(X-Y)^2] \geq \mathbb{E}_{X,Y}[X^2 - \mu(Y)^2].$$

Finally, since $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X=x] = x$, the left hand side of the above expression is just $\mathbb{E}[Y^2 - X^2]$, giving the desired expression $\mathbb{E}[Y^2 - X^2] \geq \mathbb{E}[X^2 - \mu(Y)^2].$

As for the counterexample where $f(x) = |x|$, let $X$ be Radamacher (uniform over $\{-1,1\}$) and $Y$ be $X$ plus an independent Radamacher random variable. This gives

1. $X$ is uniform over $\{-1,1\}.$
2. $Y$ is uniform over (the multiset) $\{-2,0,0,2\}$.
3. $\mu(Y)$ is uniform over $\{-1,0,0,1\}$.

Arithmetic gives that $\mathbb{E}[|X| - |\mu(Y)|] = 1/2$, but $\mathbb{E}[|Y| - |X|] = 0$, which is a counterexample.